# Error while exporting TXTextControl as PDFA or XML

Tags: vb.net, pdf, format, save, txtextcontrol

i gain a strange error: 'This feature is not available in the TX Text Control Standard or Professional version. The TX Text Control Enterprise version must be installed.' when I try to save the TXTextControl object with .Save function in .pdfa, .xml and other formats. The error comes when I explicit the StreamType parameter in the .Save function. It seems I have not all the format offered by TXTextControl.

Error comes in this line for example:

```
TXTextControl.Save(dir, TXTextControl.StreamType.XMLFormat)
```

or

```
TXTextControl.Save(dir, TXTextControl.StreamType.AdobePDFA)
```

I searched online but I can't find references to this error and for TXTextControl enterprise or professional version.

There 's actually different versions of TXTextControl? How can I verify what version I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TXTextControl.GetVersionInfo().Level should tell you what level you have (as per [ProductLevel property](https://docs.textcontrol.com/textcontrol/windows-forms/ref.txtextcontrol.versioninfo.productlevel.property.htm))

If you look at the [Features page](https://www.textcontrol.com/products/windows-forms/tx-text-control-dotnet/features/) and open up the Supported Formats section under "Features in Detail" then you can see which formats your product level supports.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't accepted your answer for a while. Thanks for the answer.